# Listbox multiselect using e.added

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I need some help implementing a multi-select on a listBbox control. At the moment I am able to display the information for one selection using the code below however I undestand it is possible to use e.added in my itemsSource to enable multiselect. Would appreciate any help. Thanks - Ben

```
private void contactsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        ContactList selectedContact = contactsList.SelectedItem as ContactList;


        tagsList.ItemsSource = new List<ContactList> { selectedContact };//??


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to comprehend and vague, i'll just assume you want to set that tagsList.ItemsSource to the all the selected ContactLists.

```
    private void contactsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ContactList> list = new List<ContactList>();
        foreach (object contactList in contactsList.SelectedItems)
        {
            list.Add(contactList as ContactList);
        }

        tagsList.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

Edit: If you in fact haven't set `ListBox.SelectionMode` you should of course do that first.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I was not very clear, if i simply change the selection mode to multiple it still only displays the information associated with first selection rather than the information from all selected items. Make sense?

Comment: I logically deduced as much from your code, you did indeed not express yourself very clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. So i have 2 listboxes contactsList and tagsList. At the moment when I click on an item in contactsList a piece of information is displayed on tagsList. So my problem was that I wanted to be able to multiselect items in contactsList and then display all the corresponding information in tagsList. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Multi-selection capabilites are built in to the listbox control...

Have you set ListBox.SelectionMode?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean however if i simply change the selection mode to multiple it still only displays the information associated with first selection rather than the information from all selected items. Make sense?

Comment: use the SelectedItems property instead of SelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Selection in a list box is achieved by setting the SelectionMode property on the list box instance to either Extended or Multiple (Extended means you need to hold down the SHIFT key and with Multiple you dont).

```
lstBox.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Controls.SelectionMode.Extended;
```

To access the selected items you then get the value of the **lstBox.SelectedItems** property.

In the example you give - you could do something similar to the following:

```
tagsList.ItemsSource = contactList.SelectedItems;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes thank you that seems to work apologies for the vague question

Comment: Cool :) as long as it works. Please rate the answer if it was helpfull. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this. it will add items to `tagsList` when selection made on `contactsList` using `e.AddedItems`

```
private void contactsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tagsList.Items.Add(((ListBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Content.ToString());
}
```